# Truffle glitch after Plantera?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is there a Truffle glitch where you can't get them when after you beat Plantera? I got him in my old world, and can't get him in my new world. In which I beat Plantera, I even saw someone say you can't get him after defeating Plantera.

Comment: Have you made sure that you have a house in a surface Mushroom Biome?

Comment: yes, I have and I made two mushroom biomes, while waiting for a hour but I'm not getting him.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question theorizes "Yes, there is." But I just noticed both questions are old, and the bug seems to have been fixed now.